# Angular 2. How to understand that Angular finished rendering after input data had changed?

Tags: angular

I have a component, let's call it `UserComponent`. This component contains grid component for showing data. There are buttons in cell for each row, delete, edit, graph, and so on. This is simplified html tempalte of this component:

```
<div>
   ...grid component goes here
   ... and other stuff
   <app-edit-user-graph [user]="selectedUser" [department]="department" [organization]="organization"></app-edit-user-graph>
</div>
```

When user clicks on `Graph` button inside cell I handle it:

`this.selectedUser = this.tableApi.row($tr).data();`

And, as you can see the `selecedUser` is passed to another component, to `app-edit-user-graph`.

This component is modal window and has a lot of select components and other controls. This is part of its template:

```
<th *ngFor="let name of heads">
   <div>
      <span>{{name}}</span>
      <span>
      <ng-select [items]="userProjects" 
         [allowClear]="true"
         (data)="update($event, name)"          
         [active]="setActive(name)">
      </ng-select>
      </span>
   </div>
</th>
```

I listen changes in `app-edit-user-graph` component:

```
@ViewChildren(SelectComponent)
selects: SelectComponent[];

@Input() user: User;
... other inputs

ngOnChanges(changes) {
   if (!changes.user || (changes.user && !changes.user.currentValue.id)) {
      return;
   }

   this.userService.getUserProjects(this.user.id).subscribe(p=> {
      this.userProjects = p;
      this.updateSelects();
   } 

} 

public updateSelects() {
    let rowSelects = this.selects;
    let selectedValues = this.getSelectedValue(rowSelects);
    let availableValues = this.getAvailableValues(selectedValues, this.userProjects);

    rowSelects.forEach(s => {
            s.items = availableValues;
    })
}
```

The method `this.updateSelects` gets all select component and filter some values.
The problem is the following. When I click the first time then `selects` in `updateSelects` method is empty. I understand why, because Angular had not finished rendering selects. When I open modal again, for other record I get previous set of select.

So, the question is, how to understand that Angular finished rendering after input data had changed?

Comment: Can you make a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5) example?

Comment: @adriancarriger it will be very difficult, because of grid and other 3-rd party components.

Answer (score 2):

This code sets `userProjects` and immediately calls `updateSelects()`.

```
  this.userProjects = p;
  this.updateSelects();
```

Angular doesn't get a chance to do anything in between.
With an explicit call to change detection, you can instruct Angular do update the DOM:

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngOnChanges(changes) {
   if (!changes.user || (changes.user && !changes.user.currentValue.id)) {
      return;
   }

   this.userService.getUserProjects(this.user.id).subscribe(p=> {
      this.userProjects = p;
      this.cdRef.detectChanges(); // <<== enforce change detection
      this.updateSelects();
   } 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understand the problem. Angular has not finished updating dom while I am  updating elements. Therefore, I get old selects. I've tried your suggestion, but don't see any changes. Does `detectChanges` run async? I need event or something else in order to understand when Angular has udated my dom and I can use my `updateSelects`.

Comment: `detectChanges()` runs sync. It's not clear from your question what `rowSelects` is.

Comment: this is the array of `SelectComponent`. `SelectComponent` is ng-select library

Comment: You have to use `detectChanges` with changes to that array. Because the code in your question doesn't show this part, I don't know how to help you.

Comment: All code in the question. In the template you can see `ng-select` tag. In the component I get all selects via ```@ViewChildren(SelectComponent)
selects: SelectComponent[];```.

Comment: There is nothing that demonstrates where `SelectComponent`s are created.

Comment: ```SelectComponent``` is ```ng-select```. ```import {SelectComponent} from "ng2-select";```.

Comment: In the view template you can see how they are created and in component how I rettrieve them via @ViewChildren

Comment: Sorry, if you don't provide the information I need I can't help you.

Comment: I can't understand what information you want :) You said that `rowSelect` is not clear for you. In the code you can see ```let rowSelects = this.selects;```. What is `selects` I described and showed code from question. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: As far as I understand `<th *ngFor="let name of heads">` is what creates the selects. There is no information about `heads` in your question. I can only assume that `SelectComponent` is related to `<ng-select>`. I have no way of knowing what's going on in your code when the connections are missing.